# Javascript Dealing With Errors

Tags: javascript, exception

I wanted to know what javascript is doing when it encounters errors (uncaught with a catch block) . Let's say I have a simple syntax error , I forgot to close a function call with a closing parenthesis : Does javascript kill the script , try to guess what I meant and continue or does this change from browser to browser? I know from experience that missing semicolons after statements won't necessarily kill your script , is this because the javascript engine can still 'understand' what the programmer meant despite his mistake?

Comment: The behaviour is browser-specific.  In firefox, for example, the engine will stop executing the script from this exception onward.  If it's a syntax error, then most likely the entire will be ignored.

Comment: Semicolons are recovered by the JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion technique. Syntax errors are fatal errors, they will always halt the execution of the current script block.